# Trigger on Update on SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I would like to update one Column value for certain condition for a SQL Server table.
I have the following code for creation of table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EQUIPMENT](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL,
 [Equipment] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
 [Facility] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
 [EquipmentType] [smallint] NULL,
 [Active] [bit] NOT NULL)
```

Following are the Insert and Update Statements

```
INSERT INTO [Equipment] ([Equipment],[Facility],[EquipmentType],[Active]) VALUES ('E02','1029',10,1)
UPDATE [Equipment] Set Active = 0 where [Equipment] = 'E01'
```

Following is the Trigger script

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ATRG_EquipmentTypeUpdate
ON [dbo].[Equipment]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN   
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- update your table, using a set-based approach
   -- from the "Inserted" pseudo table which CAN and WILL
   -- contain multiple rows!
   UPDATE [dbo].[Equipment] 
   SET  EquipmentType  = 15 
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE [dbo].[Equipment].ID = i.ID
   AND [dbo].[Equipment].EquipmentType = 10
END
GO
```

As I try to Run the Insert OR update statement - I have the following error.

```
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ATRG_EquipmentTypeUpdate1, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 9]
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).
```

Can any body advise? There are three other triggers in the table.
This, I need as a temporary solution, for workaround.

Comment: Why not actually fix the actual problem, rather than implementing a (broken) workaround?

Comment: Because, not every thing is in your control :). Guys on vacation and impending DEMO :).

Comment: Your [script](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab9fc2990fbd371d11142a77219ea320) does not, by itself, cause that problem. There is more to this than you post. But I suggest you add as the second statement to your trigger `if not exists (select * from inserted where EquipmentType = 10 return;` Won't hurt, might help

Comment: Then delay the demo... The last thing I would ever want would be a demo coming up and a developer who has no idea what they are doing "fixing" an issue that has come up just before said demo.

Comment: More explanation - I noticed the name `ATRG_EquipmentTypeUpdate1` in your error does not match your code. Which means the problem lies within the collection of triggers you have defined on your table. When a trigger updates the table on which it is defined, that action will generally cause all update triggers to execute **again**. Your trigger code should always check to see if rows were updated (or inserted or deleted - depending on the action of the trigger definition) to avoid pointless execution. A trigger will execute even if no rows were affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` to check for recursive calls.

You should also check for no rows in `inserted`.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ATRG_EquipmentTypeUpdate
ON [dbo].[Equipment]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID, 'AFTER', 'DML') > 1
      OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
       RETURN;

   -- update your table, using a set-based approach
   -- from the "Inserted" pseudo table which CAN and WILL
   -- contain multiple rows!
   UPDATE 
   SET EquipmentType = 15 
   FROM Inserted i
   JOIN [dbo].[Equipment] e ON e.ID = i.ID
     AND e.EquipmentType = 10;
END
```

Note also the use of proper `JOIN` syntax in the update.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger that updates its table won't fire again unless you opt-in to [Recursive Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#recursive-triggers), so check the RECURSIVE TRIGGERS database setting, and if it's on, turn it off:

```
alter database current set recursive_triggers off
```

Or code your trigger to not perform an UPDATE of zero rows, eg

```
if not exists (select * from inserted) return
```