# Using SQL Server triggers, how to keep data in two identical tables the same without going in a infinite loop?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I know that probably the best way to acomplish this would be to make some changes in the application code to save all changes in both tables, but the company ordered to make this happens with database logic, using triggers. So, there are two different databases, both with a table named User, and they both have the same model already. What I insert/update in User on database X have to be inserted/updated in table User on database Y, and **vice-versa**.

I managed to make the insert and update trigger going in one direction (database X -> database Y), but now i'm thinking that when I create the trigger on database Y, a loop would happen. What is missing or what can I do to make the trigger loop not happen?
This is what I have created for now on one of the databases:

```
---insert trigger
USE [DATABASE_Y]
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_USER_OnInsert] ON [dbo].[USER]
AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

        INSERT INTO [DATABASE_X].[dbo].[USER] (
                usu_id,
                usu_name,
                usu_block,
                usu_login,
                usu_password
        )
        SELECT 
                usu_id,
                usu_name,
                usu_block,
                usu_login,
                usu_password
        FROM INSERTED

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
```

`---update trigger
USE [DATABASE_Y]
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_USER_OnUpdate] ON [dbo].[USER]
AFTER UPDATE
AS`

BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

    UPDATE X
    SET 
        X.usu_id        = INSERTED.usu_id,
        X.usu_name      = INSERTED.usu_name,
        X.usu_block     = INSERTED.usu_block,
        X.usu_login     = INSERTED.usu_login,
        X.usu_password  = INSERTED.usu_password
    FROM [DATABASE_X].[dbo].[USER] X
    INNER JOIN inserted ON X.usu_login = inserted.usu_login

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

END

Comment: Why do you need 2 tables to be identical in the first place? This feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Why do you need two copies of the table at all? There are so many better ways to do this without trying to maintain two copies (views or synonyms over linked servers, caching layer, smarter application), or automatic ways depending on the context (replication, log shipping, availability groups). For a company to order you to do it exactly this way seems kind of short-sighted. "Using a tricycle, what is the fastest way to get from Miami to Los Angeles?"

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a `SYNONYM`?

Comment: add a where not exists() for the insertion and a where not all columns equal for the update

Comment: Just to clarify, the identical tables are in two distinct databases, for different applications. Basically what they initially asked was for these applications to have the same users (logins, passwords, etc) and keep them always sincronized. But because they are always in a hurry, they don't want to make changes in the code, but rather "solve" the problem using this method I told in the question (using triggers). I know this is not the recommended way, but still, I have my hands tied in their decision.

Comment: Why not have the application just access the credential's database directly then, if both applications need to use the same credentials? Replicating the credentials is pointless. Otherwise, use a `SYNONYM`, like I mentioned; then the SQL *looks* like it's referencing one object, but it's actually referencing another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger on Update on SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70067875/trigger-on-update-on-sql-server-table) Use the `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` function

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. There are a number of different ways to solve this problem, most of them are better than using triggers.

That said...

As part of your triggered code, create some variables in memory then run a select on the target database to fill them before running your update / insert. Use some simple logic to check that the values aren't already set to those same values, and avoid getting into a loop.

something like this for your update trigger:

```
USE [DATABASE_Y]
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_USER_OnUpdate] ON [dbo].[USER]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @id as varchar(100)
DECLARE @name as varchar(100)
DECLARE @block as varchar(100)
DECLARE @login as varchar(100)
DECLARE @password as varchar(100)

SELECT @id = X.usu_id,
       @name = X.usu_name,
       @block = X.usu_block,
       @login = X.usu_login,
       @password = X.usu_password
  FROM [DATABASE_X].[dbo].[USER] X
 WHERE X.usu_login = inserted.usu_login

    IF @id <> INSERTED.usu_id
    OR @name <> INSERTED.usu_name
    OR @block <> INSERTED.usu_block
    OR @login <> INSERTED.usu_login
    OR @password <> INSERTED.usu_password
 BEGIN
         UPDATE X
        SET 
            X.usu_id        = INSERTED.usu_id,
            X.usu_name      = INSERTED.usu_name,
            X.usu_block     = INSERTED.usu_block,
            X.usu_login     = INSERTED.usu_login,
            X.usu_password  = INSERTED.usu_password
        FROM [DATABASE_X].[dbo].[USER] X
        INNER JOIN inserted ON X.usu_login = inserted.usu_login
   END

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
```

I don't know what your datatypes are so I just assumed varchar(100) for everything.

Make sure that all of the columns are NOT NULL. If you have any Nullable columns, make sure you add ISNULL logic to the variable comparisons.

The insert trigger is a little easier, since you just need to check that the userId you're trying to insert doesn't already exist:

```
USE [DATABASE_Y]
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_USER_OnInsert] ON [dbo].[USER]
AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

     IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [DATABASE_X].[dbo].[USER] WHERE usu_login = INSERTED.usu_login)
  BEGIN
  
        INSERT INTO [DATABASE_X].[dbo].[USER] (
                usu_id,
                usu_name,
                usu_block,
                usu_login,
                usu_password
        )
        SELECT 
                usu_id,
                usu_name,
                usu_block,
                usu_login,
                usu_password
        FROM INSERTED
    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
```